# Python module shows up in pip freeze, but cannot be imported

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-3.7

I'm in Win10 and use vanilla Python 3.7.3 (e.g. not conda or anything). I had a successful pip install for the package, the package shows up in pip freeze, and the package is supposed to be compatible with my version of Python. I've seen several threads with similar issues on OS X and Linux, and have tried to emulate their solutions on Windows, but no luck. I'm guessing it could be an issue with my PATH variable, but I'm not quite sure. The error I get when trying to import is the "No module named" error.

Comment: What is the name of the module? What command did you use to install it?

Comment: Check the location with `python3 -m pip -v list` if you spot any irregularities.

Comment: @Anwarvic biopython; "pip3 install biopython". It's worked for every other module I have installed.

Comment: @VPfB everything's the same for the new module vs the others I have installed that work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went into site-packages...for some reason the module was named Bio there (everywhere else it's named biopython, again, including pip freeze) and importing that worked. Not sure if this was just a bad dev choice or what.

Comment: It is correctly named as per `setup.py`. See code https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/setup.py